# Regex to get a string in frame

Tags: python, regex

I have a 30 character string. I am looking for a YYDF in the middle. I want the YYDF to start at the 17 character..

```
 ................YYDF...........
```

However I want a +/- of 2 characters so it can be found in the 15th to 19th character.

Either

```
 ...............YYDF...........
```

or

```
 ..............YYDF...........
```

etc..

Comment: Isn't this a perfect case for [`string.index`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.index) rather than a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a RegExp seems like overkill, but to answer the question you can match any sequence of 15-19 characters and then your string like this:

```
re.match(r'.{15,19}YYDF', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("YYDF")
pattern.match("wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwYYDFwwwwwwwwww", 16) # shold return string match object if matches 17th character is YYDF
```

By this way you can check whether it starts from `any` position.

```
>>>pattern.match(a, 10)
None

>>>pattern.match(a, 16)
<_sre.SRE_Match at 0x7ff04a067b90>

>>>pattern.match(a, 16).group()
'YYDF'
```